# Call a Python function in a file with command-line argument

Tags: python, arguments, command-line-arguments, sys

I'm trying to pass arguments from Node.js to Python with `child_process` spawn. I also want to invoke the specific Python function with one of the argument that I specified in the Node.js array.

`test.js`

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

const exec = (file, fnCall, argv1, argv2) => {
  const py = spawn('python', [path.join(__dirname, file), fnCall, argv1, argv2]);
  py.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
    const textChunk = chunk.toString('utf8'); // buffer to string
    const array = textChunk.split(', ');
    console.log(array);
  });
};
exec('lib/test.py', 'test', 'argument1', 'argument2'.length - 2);  // => [ 'argument1', '7' ]
exec('lib/test.py', 'test', 'arg3', 'arg4'.length - 2);  // => [ 'arg3', '2' ]
```

The second argument here is `test`, which should call the `test()` Python function.

`lib/test.py`:

```
import sys

def test():
    first_arg = sys.argv[2]
    second_arg = sys.argv[3]
    data = first_arg + ", " + second_arg
    print(data, end="")

sys.stdout.flush()
```

If I try to run this Python file without any Node.js from the command line, the execution looks like this:

`$ python lib/test.py test arg3 2`

Where `test`, `arg3`, and `2` are just command-line arguments, but `test` should call the `test()` function, which will use the `arg3`, `2` arguments for `print()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to parse the command line arguments. Then you can use [eval](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#eval) to get the actual function from the input.

```
import argparse

def main():
    # Parse arguments from command line
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    # Set up required arguments this script
    parser.add_argument('function', type=str, help='function to call')
    parser.add_argument('first_arg', type=str, help='first argument')
    parser.add_argument('second_arg', type=str, help='second argument')

    # Parse the given arguments
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Get the function based on the command line argument and 
    # call it with the other two command line arguments as 
    # function arguments
    eval(args.function)(args.first_arg, args.second_arg)

def test(first_arg, second_arg):
    print(first_arg)
    print(second_arg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank You! Works perfectly!

Comment: @Lanti No problem, glad to help

Comment: What if the number of parameters required for each function is different?